# Interleave two lists of strings

Tags: c#, iterator, iteration

I've got a fairly simple task here, but I think it's worth trying to perfect the implementation, because I can probably learn a thing or two about using .NET's enumerables correctly in the process.

I have two "lists" of strings, let's call them `values` and `separators`. The former is one element longer than the latter, and I want to interleave them into a single string (so I want to riffle the separators in between the values). Example:

```
var values = new []{ "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var separators = new []{ "123", "456" };

// expected result: "abc123def456ghi"
```

I need this in a few places, and in my actual code these might be `List`s or other enumerables, so I figured I'd add an extension method to `IEnumerable<string>`, which I call on the values and pass the separators as an argument. Here's what I've got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Retina.Extensions
{
    public static class EnumerableExtension
    {
        public static string Riffle(this IEnumerable<string> values, IEnumerable<string> separators)
        {
            if (values.Count() != separators.Count() + 1)
                throw new Exception("Riffled enumerable needs to be one shorter than this enumerable.");

            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            var zipped = values.Zip(separators, (val, sep) => new { val, sep });

            foreach (var pair in zipped)
            {
                builder.Append(pair.val);
                builder.Append(pair.sep);
            }

            builder.Append(values.Last());

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, `IEnumerable` is generally a lazy list, so both `Count()` and `Last()` potentially incur an additional iteration through the entire list, which seems unnecessary. Also, the intermediate `zipped` enumerable seems awkward for something as simple as alternatingly iterating through two lists.

Is there a more idiomatic way to implement this and make better use of .NET's collections/enumerables? Is `IEnumerable` even the correct choice here?

Comment: Hint: `yield`  [complying w/ comment min length requirement]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right about enumerating both parameters multiple times. Each call to `Count` or `Last` will *execute* the enumerator. This might of course become very inefficient, especially if your collections have a lot of items.

So what could you do instead? Well, one option would be to replace `IEnumerable` with the next closest type which is the `ICollection`. This would guarantee that both collections are already materialized. This however is rarely a good solution so it's preferable to keep it lazy.

But for this, simple LINQ is not enough. You need to work with enumerators directly and implement your extension in such a way that it uses the `GetEnumerator` method. With it you have the complete control over the enumeration process. With a little bit of logic you can keep you parameters lazy and still be able to validate that the are more values then separators.

You do this by first getting the first value. Then the `while` will try to get a pair of separators and values to append them to the string. If at some point it could get a separator but not a value, it means that there is at least the same number of separators as values and at this point you can throw an exception. The other case is when there are not enough separators. To detect this you just need to try to get another value after the `while`. If it works then it means there were not enough separators.

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, IEnumerable<string> separators)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    using (var value = values.GetEnumerator())
    using (var separator = separators.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (value.MoveNext())
        {
            result.Append(value.Current);

            while (separator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (value.MoveNext())
                {
                    result
                        .Append(separator.Current)
                        .Append(value.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("There are too many separators!");
                }
            }

            if (value.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There are not enough separators!");
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would also call this extension `Join` because this is what it does.

Comment: +1 Good one, except for one small detail: this doesn't throw if there are too many *values*.

Comment: This is nice, thank you! Good catch on chaining the `Append` commands, and as opposed to my original code this also works when the value list is empty. :) I suppose the way to address Pieter's comment would be to do a `if (value.MoveNext()) throw ...` after the loop?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet oops, you're right. I've added a fix.

Comment: @MartinEnder exactly! I guess we wrote it at the same time ;-)

Comment: Remember the "exit early" principle. Change the outermost `if (value.MoveNext())` to `if (!value.MoveNext()) return "";` then you don't have to indent the whole code.

Comment: @Snowbody I agree and I usually do that but in certain situations like here I prefer to use positive conditions everywhere (I find it's easier to read because the block is rather small) so this is an exception to the _rule_ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not [`Count()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1305) requires a new iteration depends on how the `IEnumerable<T>` object is wired. The framework is smart enough to know that if the object implements `ICollection<T>` *("unordered")* it should invoke the `Count` property. If not, `GetEnumerator()` is invoked and the returned enumerator iterated.

The same logic applies for [`Last()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1079). If the object implements `IList<T>` *(ordered)*, then the `Count` property is used to calculate the position, and a call to the indexer returns the element.

So by using your example variables, no extra iteration is required as `string[]` implements both `ICollection<string>` and `IList<string>`.

Now, with that being said, I would rather move the constraint check from the callee to the caller, rending the function more flexible.
Then invoke [`string.Join`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,161) which under the hood use `StringBuilder` to compose the final string.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Interleave<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source1, IEnumerable<TSource> source2)
    {

        if (source1 == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source1)); }
        if (source2 == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source2)); }

        using (var enumerator1 = source1.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (var enumerator2 = source2.GetEnumerator())
            {

                var continue1 = true;
                var continue2 = true;

                do
                {

                    if (continue1 = enumerator1.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield return enumerator1.Current;
                    }

                    if (continue2 = enumerator2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        yield return enumerator2.Current;
                    }

                }
                while (continue1 || continue2);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

## Example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbSXp2

```
string[] values;
string[] separators;

values = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
separators = new[] { "1", "2" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", values.Interleave(separators)));

values =  new[] { "a", "b" };
separators = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" }; 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", values.Interleave(separators)));

values = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
separators = new[] { "1", "2" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", values.Interleave(separators)));
```

> a1b2c
>   a1b23456
>   a1b2cdef

Comment: Unfortunately it is supposed to be an error if the size of `values` is anything other than one more than the size of `separators`.

Comment: Understood. But I still think the "best" design would be to leave the constraint check to the caller and not the callee. :)